# How to import symbols from a Exporter Perl module using require?

Tags: perl, import, module, perl-module, exporter

I like to `import` symbols from an `Exporter` powered Perl module using `require` and not `use`. Perl don't know the variable he just imported.

Perl module sample:

```
package TheModule;
use strictures;
use base 'Exporter';
use Const::Fast qw( const );
const our $TEST_VAR_1 => 'Test variable 1';
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( $TEST_VAR_1 );
our %EXPORT_TAGS = ( TEST_VAR => [qw( $TEST_VAR_1 )] );
```

Perl script sample

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strictures;
require TheModule;
TheModule->import( ':TEST_VAR' );
printf "Test variable 1 contains: %s\n", $TEST_VAR_1;
```

The following example works, but I have to use `require` instead of `use`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strictures;
use TheModule ( ':TEST_VAR' );
printf "Test variable 1 contains: %s\n", $TEST_VAR_1;
```

How to import `$TEST_VAR_1` within the `require` environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`our @EXPORT_TAGS` should be `our %EXPORT_TAGS`. :)

---

Alright, there is something else wrong. At compile time, when

```
printf "Test variable 1 contains: %s\n", $TEST_VAR_1;
```

is being transformed into ops, `$TEST_VAR_1` does not exist in that scope yet, since

```
TheModule->import( ':TEST_VAR' );
```

is executed only at runtime. So, unless you put a `BEGIN{}` around your require and import, this cannot work.

Comment: Unfortunately this was only a typo which I now have fixed. The problem still exists.